# Is there a custom character creator addon in Blender?

Tags: modeling, add-on, sculpting

Basically I’m trying to make some characters in sculpt mode, I can do it but it takes me a good few days to make it look the way I want and then it comes to texturing and that’s where it all falls apart, I can’t get them to look right.

I wonder if there is a custom character creator addon. What I'm looking for is sort of like [The Sims character creator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8FT-vZrKhM) with sliders and pre-textured skin and hair and pre-exsisting facial features.

Ideally I want as high resolution and realistic as possible, it’s for a card game so poly count does not matter and they don’t need to be rigged I can add that bit later on, clothing is not much of a problem as I can make clothes

Was wandering if anyone on here knows of a add on like this or any other software that could do what I need, maybe I’m going about this all wrong and maybe you have an easier solution.

Comment: MB-Lab is a good choice for realism and anime.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the already mentioned [MakeHuman](http://makehumancommunity.org/) (which actually started as a Blender Add-on but is now a standalone application) there is also [Manuel Bastioni Lab](https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io/).

It is a Blender Addon that allows parameter driven custom character creator directly inside the Blender viewport, in a similar vein to MakeHuman.

It can create realistic human figures as well as fantasy or anime themed characters.

Comment: Ok thanks for that I’ll have a look into those two and see if I can make them work for me thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if such an add-on exists for Blender itself but you might want to take a look at the [MakeHuman](http://makehumancommunity.org) software which, I've heard, is pretty good at what it does. It is made to quickly design human meshes based on parameters along with hairs and clothes. Plus, it seems to be working quite well with Blender and the wiki even has a chapter about using [MakeHuman Models in Blender](http://www.makehumancommunity.org/wiki/Documentation:Index#Working_with_MakeHuman_models_in_Blender)

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand the list, there is also the (paid, closed-source) [Adobe Fuse](https://www.adobe.com/products/fuse.html) which I've been having a lot of success with. It can export models in a variety of formats that are compatible with Blender, and is also integrated with [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/), an automatic animation library/service.

Comment: Super cool! I had no idea, so thanks for sharing. I just used Mixamo to make a test animation, and the .FBX imported into Blender (2.79) just fine.